# How do I find the request method from Go Gin context?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to use the same handler for multiple endpoints in a Go Gin app:

```
    router.POST("/box/:boxID", controllers.AddUpdateBox)
    router.PUT("/box/:boxID", controllers.AddUpdateBox)
    router.PATCH("/box/:boxID", controllers.AddUpdateBox)
```

In the controller I want to find what is the request method (POST, PUT or PATCH).

```
func AddUpdateBox(c *gin.Context) {
  
}
```

How do I get the request method from the Gin context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
c.Request.Method
```

This member represents the method of the request

Answer (score 3):

```
c.Request.Method
```

Struct [http.Request](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) on Package `net/http` has a property called `Method` that can be used to check the method on a currently running request.